# Batch script to deploy PowerPoint .ppa plugin

Tags: batch-file, powerpoint

I know how to do this through the interface:

`Tools -> Add-ins`

But is there any way I can deploy a .ppa PowerPoint plugin programatically, preferably so it doesn't prompt a Macro security warning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article about this on the PowerPoint FAQ that I maintain.  I'd have answered sooner but I needed to update it a bit and add some new info.  That's done.

Add / install an addin via the registry
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00469_Add_-_install_an_addin_via_the_registry.htm

Comment: I have a .PPA file that I want to distribute via installer? How to do it?

Comment: Basically, have the installer copy your files to the directory you want to install it to then set the registry entries as described above.